# Who to email based on attachment file

Tags: powershell

Without using a ton of ElseIf statements is it possible to select the the recipient of an email based on the file that will be attached to the email while iterating over all files in a folder?

I have started building this without the foreach get-ChildItem running over the folder where I create the email object, assign specific recipients, and choose a specific file out of the folder, but this is quite tedious and repetitive. I feel like there has to be a way to use an array of arrays or something where based on the file that the loop is on it pulls through the recipients and maybe a custom subject line.

There's tons of powershell email code out there so I won't repost that. Just not sure how to even attack this.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Chris20973. Please have a look through some of the help at https://stackoverflow.com/help to see how SO operates. The goal here is for you to get your code working. Yes, we all know there is a lot of code out there. On SO, you post -your- code, tell what it should do, and tell what is is doing (including any error messages).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have an accompanying CSV file, with rows for the filename, the recipient and the subject name etc. You could then import the CSV file using *Import-Csv*.

For example:

```
$emailList = Import-csv c:\users.csv

foreach ($line in $emailList) {
  Write-Host "Sending message to $($line.emailAddress)"
  Send-MailMessage -To $line.emailAddress `
    -Subject $line.subject `
    -Attachments $line.attachmentPath `
    -Body $line.bodyText
}
```

and if you wanted to define the contents of the CSV in the PowerShell script, rather than using an external file, you could do something like:

```
$emailList = "emailAddress,subject,attachmentPath,bodyText
joe@bloggs.com,Attachment for Joe,c:\attachmentsToSend\joe.pdf,Attached is your file
Mary@bloggs.com,Mary's attachment,c:\attachmentsToSend\mary.pdf,Hello, Mary. Attached is your file
" | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Put that above the *foreach* loop in the script